# Naming Functions in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I just started with jQuery and the functions are confusing me. I want to be able to just name a jQuery function and then call it, without saying when it should be called in the function. I've looked and I can't seem to understand any of the answers. My code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {
            $('a').click(function() {
                $('#box').slideUp();

            });
        });
    </script>
```

I want it to do something more like this however:

```
$(function slideBox() {
        $('#box').slideUp();
    });
    </script>
```

And then call it through a OnClick event or something on a button.

Answer (score 7):

jQuery is just a library on top of Javascript, you can still have regular functions with jQuery code inside of them. The reason most examples are of the `$(function() { ... });` variety is because Javascript in general is heavily event-based and the most common time for you do to things with jQuery is on page load, which `$(function() { });` is a shortcut for.

One of the nice things about jQuery is that it lets you write unobstrusive Javascript, you really shouldn't be putting any code in the `onclick` of any HTML elements as it is a very poor practice and a maintenance nightmare. The more standard approach is:

#### HTML

```
<input type="button" id="slideMeUp" value="Up, up, and away!">
```

#### jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $('#slideMeUp').click(function() {
        $('#box').slideUp();
    });
});
```

However, you could easily have something like:

```
function slideMeUp() {
    $('#box').slideUp();
}

$(function() {
    // still need this outer function to indicate
    // to only bind the handler when the DOM is ready
    $('#slideMeUp').click(slideMeUp);
});
```

Comment: Why do I need the external function?

Comment: @JackstahComradDavis you don't, the first example is what people will usually do, the second one is to show that all it is asking for is a function for the click() event so if you wanted to have one named to call elsewhere you can still have it that way

Answer (score 1):

You are getting mixed up between jQuery, which is a Javascript library and Javascript as a whole.

To write the function slideBox() in Javascript you just do:

```
function slideBox() {
    $("#box").slideUp();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You usually need

```
$(function() { 
..
});
```

That's a shortcut of $(document).ready(function() {}) which runs when the page is loaded.

You can do this:

```js
<script>
function slideBox(speed) {
    $("#box").slideUp(speed);
}

$(function() {
    slideBox(300);
});
</script>
```

Or you can create your own plugins like this:

```
(function($) {

$.fn.FunctionName = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).slideUp();
    });
};

})(jQuery);
```

you can save that in a separate file and then do something like this:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#box").FunctionName();
    });
</script>
```

Have a look at this:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any difference between a JavaScript function and a jQuery function; it's the same technology.

If you want to define a function that slides the box up, just write one, and then hook it up to the onclick event. Here's how I would do that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function slideBox() {
        $('#box').slideUp();
    }

    $(function() {
        $('a').click(function() {
            slideBox();
        });
        // or, as Paolo shows:
        $('a').click(slideBox);
    });

</script>
```

The `$(function() { });` syntax is short for:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // do things when the DOM is ready
});
```

Whatever you put inside it will be delayed until the DOM is finished loading. If the latter makes more sense to you, use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function and pass it to the click handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onClick() {
        $('#box').slideUp();
    }

    $("#MyButton").click(onClick);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your original function ie

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        $('.uniqueclass').click(function() {
            $('#box').slideUp();

        });
    });
    </script>
```

I have changed the 'a' to 'uniqueclass'
then
create a button with the class of .uniqueclass - on clicking it, the function will fire

Answer (score 0):

You don't want your function to be declared in the global scope (as a general rule), so you would declare it inside of jQuery's document ready and access your function through an event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// jQuery document's ready
$(function() {

    // your function
    var slideBox = function() {
        $('#box').slideUp();
    };

    // event
    $('a').click(function() {
        // call to your function
        slideBox();
    });

});

</script>
```